# Getting Invalid Column name Error in T-SQL while performing Update operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I am trying to run a SQL query which is quite straightforward. The query is:

```
UPDATE dbo.Machine 
SET dbo.Machine.ServerName="Server" 
WHERE dbo.Machine.ServerName IS NULL;
```

I am getting the following error on Server

```
Invalid column name 'Server'.
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: If this is SQL Server, please add SQL Server tag.  It helps people who are trying to help you.

Comment: I vote to close such questions as typographical errors.  The issue is that single quotes are how SQL delimits strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String should be declared with single quotes `' '`

```
SET dbo.Machine.ServerName= 'Server'
```

Double quotes is for fieldnames